# Swift crash when NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest returns an error

Tags: swift

Using the following code works fine UNLESS there is an `error`, then

```
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error? {
            ...
        }
        else {
           ...
        }
```

when is crashes with

> "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0"

on the **if error?** line.

Does anybody know why ?

Comment: i am using exactly same way to query url and specifically tried to generate error and working fine. no crash at all. only the difference is i declare queue as variable before the block.

Comment: Try changing `if error?` to `if error`

Comment: @JackWu Worth a try, but even an implicit optional should still let you use the optionality tests, I think... Agreensh, are you sure it's crashing on the if? Might it be crashing on the code inside the if's block? Can you try actually removing the code you've elided with "..." and see if it still crashes—remember, this stuff's all beta, and it might not be reporting the crashing line correctly...

Comment: @MattGibson Yes, implicitly unwrapped optionals behave exactly like optionals except when accessing properties or methods. To check an optional, you do `if optional` and not `if optional?`, thats the reasoning of my solution.

Comment: Oh! Yes, good point. What do you think `if whatever?` is actually being interpreted as? Now you've explained, I'm not even sure what it would by trying to do, if it's legal syntax, which of course it might not be...

Comment: None of the suggestions work. The code is actually from a tutorial.

Removing the code inside the "if error" (ie empty block) still has the same crash, so I assume it really is that line.

Comment: Where's the tutorial?

Comment: http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-ios-apps-using-swift-tutorial-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

Now  `NSURLConnection` is deprecated now you should use `NSURLSession`  instead still I am posting an example of  `NSURLConnection`

in your code you are forcefully unwrap value of `error: NSError!` `response: NSURLResponse!`,`data: NSData!` is creating problem

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL.init(string: "yourURL")!)

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (request, data, error) in
    // Here you can check error with guard and data also 
}
```

Hope it is helpful to you